# Update package data with github actions

Tags: r, shiny, github-actions, golem

I'm developing a shiny app with {golem} framework. Repo is [here](https://github.com/albersonmiranda/econdashboard) and it's deployed [here](https://albersonmiranda.shinyapps.io/econdashboard/).

It's data is generated by [this script](https://github.com/albersonmiranda/econdashboard/blob/master/data-raw/series.R) in data-raw folder. Several objects are created, put together in a list called `series` and then stored in the package as a .rda file via `usethis::use_data()`. Currently, i'm updating data manually by running that script and then pushing it and deploying to shinyapps.io.

I'd like to set a cron job in github actions to daily run that script, update `series.rda`, build the package and then deploy it to shinyapps.io.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can schedule a GitHub Actions pipeline to run every day. See here for instance: https://jasonet.co/posts/scheduled-actions/

Comment: If your question is not about how to setup "cron" jobs on GH Actions, you're probably thinking of what tools to use to actually run the script. What I would do is use a docker container that has R and possibly all the required packages installed. If not, you'll have to go through the painstaking task of doing just that. After you have a docker container ready, you can call your script using i.e. `Rscript runscript.R`.